# Access 2003/SQL matching only columns that are not null in the left table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I want to perform a left join matching rows in the right table that have the same value as those in the left. I want the join to ignore the null values in the left table and not try to match them.

If the left table column A is blank (null) than any value in the right table column A is acceptable. If the left table column B and C contain values, I want to match them in the right table.

```
+--------+--------+-------+     +--------+-------+------+
|    A   |   B    |   C   |     |   A    |   B   |   C  |
+--------+--------+-------+     +--------+-------+------+
|  Null  |   1    |   2   |     |   3    |   1   |   2  |
+--------+--------+-------+     +--------+-------+------+
                                |   5    |   1   |   2  |
                                +--------+-------+------+
                                |   7    |   1   |   2  |
                                +--------+-------+------+
```

Each of the rows in the right table above should join.

Any column in the left table could have a value or be null. How do I word a query that will only match only the columns that are populated?

I tried using AND in the ON clause and nothing joins, when I use OR, then rows join if only one column matches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each column, you need a condition to join the values if they are equal or the left value is null:

```
SELECT    t1.*, t2.*
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.a IS NULL OR t1.a = t2.a) AND
                (t1.b IS NULL OR t1.b = t2.b) AND
                (t1.c IS NULL OR t1.c = t2.c)
```